# Expo iOS module: XCFramework files are not copied

Tags: expo, xcframework, expo-module

I am trying to create a local Expo module that wraps Google Maps SDK. Ihave copied required XCFramework files under `ios/Frameworks`folder. Here is my `podspec` file:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  ...
  s.static_framework = true

  s.dependency 'ExpoModulesCore'
  s.dependency 'Alamofire'
  s.libraries = 'c++', 'z'
  s.frameworks =
    'Accelerate',
    'CoreData',
    'CoreGraphics',
    'CoreImage',
    'CoreLocation',
    'CoreTelephony',
    'CoreText',
    'GLKit',
    'ImageIO',
    'Metal',
    'OpenGLES',
    'QuartzCore',
    'SystemConfiguration',
    'UIKit'
  s.vendored_frameworks =
    'Frameworks/GoogleMaps.xcframework',
    'Frameworks/GoogleMapsBase.xcframework',
    'Frameworks/GoogleMapsCore.xcframework',
    'Frameworks/GoogleMapsM4B.xcframework'
  s.resources = "GoogleMaps.bundle"

  # Swift/Objective-C compatibility
  s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
    'DEFINES_MODULE' => 'YES',
    'SWIFT_COMPILATION_MODE' => 'wholemodule',
    'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '-lObjC'
  }
  s.source_files = "**/*.{swift}"
end
```

After pod install when I try to compile the iOS project I get link error for GoogleMaps:

```
Library not found for -lGoogleMaps
```

When I check the app content I see that the frameworks folder is empty.

How can I make the xcframework files copied to app?